# Getting invalid zip file error when I email a zip folder to myself using the EmailMessage module

Tags: python, zip, email-attachments

So first of all I'm not really sure if I'm going about attaching this zip folder the right way. I've kinda hacked together different things together, but I'm getting an error message below which I've linked towards the bottom of my code.

```
 from email.message import EmailMessage
 import shutil

 message = EmailMessage()
 message["From"] = "superdummy@idiot.com"
 message["To"] = "superdummy@idiot.com"
 message["Subject"] = "Testing Zip"

 path = "Testing.zip"

 with open(path, "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes)

 message.add_attachment(encoded, maintype='application/zip', subtype='octet-stream', filename="Testing.zip")

 s = smtplib.SMTP(host='blah.blah.yum', port=99)

 s.send_message(message)
```

When I receive the email and I try to open it up, I get the error message:

`"Windows cannot open the folder, the compressed Zip folder is invalid"`

Couldn't find similar error messages on Stackoverflow or other places. I'd really appreciate some direction. Thanks!

Comment: You've got an extra ```"``` in ```message["To"] = "superdummy@idiot.com""```

Comment: @ewong whoops didn't peep that! updated the code. still having same issue however